# Can not set the color when android:state_enabled="false"

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView and first time I display it I want to disable some of its items.

For this I made this *textorange_selected.xml*:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" 
          android:color="@color/medium_gray" />

    <item android:state_selected="true"
        android:color="@android:color/white" />

    <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:color="@android:color/white" />

    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:color="@android:color/white" />

    <item android:color="@color/lighter_orange" />
</selector>
```

and I use it in the layout of a row:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_height="20dp"
   android:gravity="left|center"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:paddingLeft="5dp"
   android:paddingRight="5dp"
   android:background="@color/list_bg">

    <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/avatar"
       android:layout_width="48dp"
       android:layout_height="48dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <LinearLayout
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="48dp"
       android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/avatar"
       android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="5dp">


           <TextView android:id="@+id/listitem1"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
               android:textColor="@drawable/textblack_selected"
               android:textSize="18dp"
               android:textStyle="bold" />

           <TextView android:id="@+id/listitem2"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
               android:textColor="@drawable/textorange_selected" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/arrowImage"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
       android:src="@drawable/arrow_selector" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is that it never enter into `android:state_enabled="false"` (that should be the moment when the item is disable and I set the color of the text to gray).

For disabling the items I use this code in my adapter:

```
@Override
public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {                    
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    return position < 1;
}
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: you are disabling the TextView in Java?

Comment: see my Edit. I put the code how I disable the items of ListView. I work in android

Comment: the relativelayout is disabled, not sure the textview is. you could try with duplicateParentState to pass the disabled status down to the textview

Answer (score 2):

The Selector uses the value `isEnabled()` on the View it's assigned to, in this case the `RelativeLayout`. It will not call `isEnabled()` on the `Adapter`.

You will need code such as:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    RelativeLayout v = (RelativeLayout)LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.listitem_relativelayout, null);
    if(postion < 1) v.setEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the enabled state returned by `isEnabled()` is **not** automatically forwarded to all the child views of a list item.
What you need to do is call `view.setEnabled()` at the end of your adapter's `getView()` method to make your selector functional.

Also, make sure you pass the state down to the descendants by specifying `android:duplicateParentState="true"` on the `TextView` itself as well as on your `LinearLayout` wrapper.